# Transferring contents

Tags: android, connection

Is it possible to transfer the contents of one application to another application using server in Android? For example an image to be transferred from one application to another app using server.

Comment: @ABDOU transferring location details obtained using one application to another application by sending the location details to server.

Comment: What server? Something built in android or an external server both apps connect to? If the first look up services and AIDL interfaces which could be used to exchange information between two apps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `server` (as in a TCP/IP server somewhere on the Internet) or do you mean `Service` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html as in an Android Service that applications use to talk to each other?

If you mean an Internet server, then of course it's trivial as long as you understand how to perform network communications.

If you mean an Android Service, you can pass any Bundle through a Service, so as long as the data you want to transfer is Parcelable (able to be placed into a Bundle) then you can transfer it.